# Laravel 5 logout is not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, logout

I tried so many ways still not able to solve this issue.

View Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        {!! HTML::link('auth/logout', 'Logout') !!}
    </body>
</html>
```

In \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php

```
public function getLogout()
    { 

        $this->auth->logout(); // OR
        // Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/auth/login');
    }
```

I tried both ways still it show error

```
Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::$auth
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What error are you getting when calling Auth::logout()? For sure not the "Undefined property"

Comment: For Auth::logout() getting this error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found"

Comment: I posted an answer on how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Auth::logout()** will work, just add

```
use Auth;
```

at the top of your controller file.

Comment: Able to logout. For  Session::flush(); it gives Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Session' not found

Comment: If you do not provide a "use" statement then the class is being loaded from current namespace (App\Http\Controllers\Auth)